# Start Test in The Middle of The Datapool in Rational Functional Tester

Tags: vb.net, functional-programming, rft

I am a newbie, as you will be able to tell soon.  I am using Rational Funcational Tester (RFT) in VB.Net.  I have a test with an associated datapool.  I have been able to run tests without issue.  All I want to do is start the test on record 5 of the datapool and run until the end.  I cannot figure out how to start on iteration 5.  Can I use some kind of Run time argument?  I am a previous user of QTP and know exactly what to look for there.  RFT is a new animal to me.
As always, I really appreciate those who take time from their busy days to teach others.  I thank you in advance for your time and efforts.

Derek

Answer (score 0):

// Assuming that the datapool is already associated with your executing script,

int targetRow = 4; // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4   i.e the 5th record

for (int i = 0; (i < targetRow) && (!dpDone()); ++i) {

```
dpNext();
```

}

// You are now positioned on row 4 (i.e. the fifth record; datapool indexes start at zero)

//You can now do things like

String username = dpString(0);